# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flickr'

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm using `Joomla Bamboo jFlickr` in my site but I'm getting this error from console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flickr'`

I tried so many things like `jQuery.noConflict()` but none of them is working.

so what is the problem?

[Site](http://lapalma-tours.com/index.php)

Comment: You have 2 versions of jQuery being imported. One which comes packed with Joomla (the correct and latest one) and another one coming from the Skitter Slideshow module. Sort this out first as it might be causing conflicts. jQuery that automatically gets imported with Joomla 3.x is already called in noConflict mode

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't do this:

```
 <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You make another request only for "`Jquery.noConflict();`"

try again after updating your jquery to **jquery 1.10**

Comment: This isn't done by choice, it's now Joomla imports jQuery using the API call